# Rising and Falling Function in Pinescript Sharks Fin

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to create a sharks fin indicator using MFI whenever it rise above 90 and 10 or falls below 10 or 90. However I can't seem to plot it correctly.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Money Flow Index", shorttitle="MFI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=7, minval=1, maxval=2000)
src = hlc3
mf = ta.mfi(src, length)
plot(mf, "MF", color=#7E57C2)
overbought=hline(80, title="Overbought", color=#787B86)
oversold=hline(20, title="Oversold", color=#787B86)
fill(overbought, oversold, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")

isRisingSell1 = ta.rising(mf, 90)
isFallingSell2 = ta.falling(mf, 90)

isFallingBuy1 = ta.falling(mf, 10)
isRisingBuy2 = ta.rising(mf, 10)


plotshape(isRisingSell1, color=color.orange, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(isFallingSell2, color=color.red, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(isFallingBuy1, color=color.lime, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(isRisingBuy2, color=color.green, style=shape.circle)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it might be better with the `crossover()` and `crossunder()` functions:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Money Flow Index", shorttitle="MFI", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
length = input.int(title="Length", defval=7, minval=1, maxval=2000)
src = hlc3
mf = ta.mfi(src, length)
plot(mf, "MF", color=#7E57C2)
overbought=hline(80, title="Overbought", color=#787B86)
oversold=hline(20, title="Oversold", color=#787B86)
fill(overbought, oversold, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="Background")

isRisingSell1 = ta.crossover(mf, 90)
isFallingSell2 = ta.crossunder(mf, 90)

isFallingBuy1 = ta.crossunder(mf, 10)
isRisingBuy2 = ta.crossover(mf, 10)


plotshape(isRisingSell1, color=color.orange, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(isFallingSell2, color=color.red, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(isFallingBuy1, color=color.lime, style=shape.circle)
plotshape(isRisingBuy2, color=color.green, style=shape.circle)
```